# What does reverse=!reverse means in angular orderby?

Tags: angularjs, sorting, html-table

I am sorting data with AngularJS. I see in AngularJS documentation https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy an example. I don't understand what does **reverse=!reverse** means in index.html. Here is the code:

```
div ng-controller="ExampleController">
  <table class="friend">
    <tr>
      <th><a href="" ng-click="reverse=false;order('name', false)">Name</a>
        (<a href="" ng-click="order('-name',false)">^</a>)</th>
      <th><a href="" ng-click="reverse=!reverse;order('phone', reverse)">Phone Number</a></th>
      <th><a href="" ng-click="reverse=!reverse;order('age',reverse)">Age</a></th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="friend in friends">
      <td>{{friend.name}}</td>
      <td>{{friend.phone}}</td>
      <td>{{friend.age}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

I did as in the example. It works but I don't understand what does the expression **reverse=!reverse** means?

Comment: it's just flipping the value of that variable each time. `Name` is reverse=false, then `Phone number` gets reverse=true, and `Age` gets reverse=false again.

Answer (score 1):

When you click the link for Phone Number or Age, the sorting of the list is put in reverse order by those columns. `reverse=!reverse;` just toggles the value of that variable from `true` to `false` or from `false` to `true` before it's passed to the `order` function.

Comment: Ok it just toggles. Thanks